# Binomial Hypothesis Test

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification, hypothesis-testing

> The proportion of deaths due to lung cancer in working males aged 15-64
>   in Australia between 1970 and 1972 was 10%. There is reason to believe
>   that working in a chemical plant for an extended period can increase your
>   risk of lung cancer. Several Australian chemical plants were investigated,
>   and it was found that of 90 deaths in working males aged 15-64, 19 were
>   due to lung cancer.
>
> Is there evidence of increased risk of developing lung cancer if you work in
>   a chemical plant?

For this hypothesis test, we are required to provide a statement of the null and alternative hypothesis, a test statistic, the observed value and the estimated $p$-value.

My Attempt:

let $p$ be the probability of developing lung cancer in a chemical plant. Therefore,
$$H_0:p=0.1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{vs} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ H_1:p>0.1$$
Our test statistic is
$$Z=\frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{where} \ Z\sim N(0,1)$$
Our observed value is therefore
$$\frac{\frac{\hat{p}}{n}-p}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}} =\frac{\frac{19}{90}-0.1}{\sqrt{\frac{0.1(1-0.1)}{90}}}=3.51$$
Hence our p-value is 
$$\mathbb{P}(Z>\text{observed value})=\mathbb{P}(Z>3.51)<0.0001$$

Hence we reject $H_0$. Is my hypothesis test correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the null hypothesis that 10% of deaths are due to lung cancer, the number $X$ of deaths at the chemical factories is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(90, .1).$
Then the P-value of $H_0: p = .1$ vs $H_a: p > .1$ is $P(X \ge 19) = 1 - P(X \le 18) = 0.0013 < 1\%.$ So $H_0$ is rejected.

```
1 - pbinom(18, 90, .1)
## 0.001308245
```

This may raise questions about hazardous conditions in chemical factories, which need to be carefully investigated. But it is not 'evidence' of increased risk due to employment in a chemical factory. There are many ways in which workers at 'several' 
chemical factories might not be typical of Australian men aged 15-64.

**Addendum per Comment:** Here is a plot of the exact (discrete) binomial distribution and its approximating (continuous) normal distribution. The P-value refers to values to the right of the vertical broken line.

[image]

*Note:* As software for computing exact distributions becomes more readily
available and easy to use, there is no reason to use a normal approximation
in many practical applications. However, the normal approximation will continue to be of
theoretical interest.

Comment: What is the distribution of your test statistic under the null hypothesis?

Comment: Yes, I agree. If I was to approximate the binomial distribution though, my P-value would approximately be <0.001, right? Although it's not stated, I believe the marking criteria insists we approximate the binomial distribution by $N(0,1)$.

Comment: Previous Comment updated: $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=90, p=0.1),$ as in my first paragraph. // Note that the normal approximation with P-value .0001 in your Question should be 0.00022 (using `1 - pnorm(3.513642)` in R), whereas the exact binomial P-value is 0.00131. The difference btw the two is the that the binomial dist'n is not _exactly_ normal. In fact, normal approximations are often good only to about two decimal places. (For tiny probabilities the _absolute_ error is small, but the _relative_ error, or percentage error, may be quite large.) See my Addendum.

Comment: If you were to _compute_ the exact binomial P-value (tediously using the binomial PDF formula or conveniently with software) you'd get P-value 0.0013 to four places. // Of course, the trouble with 'marking criteria' for multiple-choice and computer generated exercises is that they only look at answers, not thought processes.

Comment: That is true. The reason I ask is that this question is from an in-class exam (no compute access, otherwise the exam would be much easier haha) where we are only given a statistic table of standard normal probabilities. Hence, we'd be expected use this to approximate the binomial distribution. Given this, I believe my p-value would be $$\mathbb{P}\left(Z>\frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}}\right) \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{where} \ Z\sim N(0,1)$$ Do you agree?

Comment: I agree that you computed this normal approximation correctly up to the point $P(Z > 3.51).$ But that is 0.0002240533, not 0.0001. Most printed normal tables don't have values above 3.49, so I don't know how you got 0.0001 from such a table. One table I looked at has 3.50 with $P(Z > 3.50) = 0.00024.$ Also, as noted in my answer, I don't think a tiny P-value for the quoted data says much about Australian chemical workers. // If you're trying to get me to help you win an argument with your instructor, that's probably not quite enough. Sorry.

Comment: This question is in preparation for an exam next week. We are only required to provide an approximate P-value, hence $<0.001$ should suffice. I believe in this upcoming exam, we will be provided output from R (as opposed to stats tables), so this should eliminate any guess work when it comes to calculating the P-value for $N(0,1)$. Thank you for your very thorough responses :).

Comment: Well, I hope you're as ready for the rest of the topics on the test as you seem to be for this one.